# How to convert binary floating point numbers to decimal numbers with verilog？

Tags: binary, verilog, decimal-point

I am writing a program. there is a binary floating number like this format : XX.XXX. for example,binary floating number 01.101 convert to decimal number is 1.625. I tried it for a long time, but couldn't work it out.

I use [4:0]num to store the number. num[4:3] is the integer part, num[2:0] is the floating part. the integer part is easy, when num[2:0]=3'b101, it means that the binary floating part is 0.101, and convert to decimal number is 0.625. so how can I convert the sequence"101", get a sequence "625"?

Comment: Note that your format "XX.XXX" is called a fixed-point number. When speaking about a 'floating point' number you have a significant and exponent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic.

Comment: Also, is this for simulation or synthesis (for display on an LCD or 7seg or something)?

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is probably just to use a LUT (lookup table). Since the fractional portion is only 3 bits, that leaves you with only 8 possibilities. And you could use an 12bit value where each nibble is a digit that could be sent to a display etc.

```
reg result[11:0] // each nibble represents a digit

always @(*) begin
    case (num[2:0])
        3'b000  : result = 12'h000;
        3'b001  : result = 12'h125;
        3'b010  : result = 12'h250;
        3'b011  : result = 12'h375;
        3'b100  : result = 12'h500;
        3'b101  : result = 12'h625;
        3'b110  : result = 12'h750;
        default : result = 12'h875;
    endcase    
end
```